# How does a java and angular project work and communicate with each other?

Tags: java, angular

I am creating a website using Java 8 for the back end and Angular 6 for the front end. I am very new the angular, so I have been doing my research about creating and building angular projects. I still do not understand how the front end and the back end communicate with each other. How does angular call a java method? How does java send information back to angular? I understand that java will being be handling all of my logic/model part of the program and angular will be handling the view, but I can't wrap my mind around how two different languages communicate in this way.

Comment: They talk using the protocol of the web: HTTP. Angular sends HTTP requests to the backend, without caring if it's implemented in Java, C#, Python, Perl or whatever. The Java backend receives HTTP requests, and sends back HTTP responses. The content of the request and the response is typically a JSON document, that both sides are easily able to generate and parse.

Comment: They would usually communicate via HTTP. Have a look into RESTful endpoints in java, that should answer most of your questions

Comment: I don't think you will understand anything with this sort of approach try https://medium.com/@swhp/build-single-page-application-with-java-ee-and-angularjs-4eaacbdfcd it's a medium post. it explains well everything. I am also following the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, the Angular client will use HttpClient to send RESTful calls to a service, using JSON payloads. The Java back end will expose RESTful services that return JSON. So, the answer is RESTful services and JSON allow the two sides to communicate.

Comment: HTTP and REST are not really interchangeable though. Many simple things (e.g. password resetting) do not have an obvious solution with REST, either, further complicating things if you want to be fully *RESTful*.

Answer (score 1):

Today, almost all modern frontend frameworks are using REST APIs to communicate with backend.

REST APIs are a good and simple way to integrate systems, there is a framework called SpringBoot that can simplifier a lot your life for java backend.

Here is a simple example -> https://dzone.com/articles/building-your-first-spring-boot-web-application-ex

After you have an api running, you can call it from your angular services.